# PHP: Parse column name values from MySQL query statements?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, parsing

I'm trying to build audit logging for a website.  What I want to do is allow existing MySQL queries to go in unchanged (if possible) to a PHP function which parses the data and stores it in the audit log table.

For example, if I have the query

```
UPDATE members SET name='Bob', age='40' WHERE memberId=123
```

then I'd like to be able to pull out the table name `members`, the rowId `123` and both column/data (as if key/value) pairs `name:Bob` and `age:40`.

If possible I'd like a solution which also allows for the alternative query format:

```
UPDATE members (name,age) VALUES ('Bob','40') WHERE memberId=123
```

These would then go into an audit log table which would look something like this:

```
+--------+---------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+
| user   | table   | column | row | old_value | new_value |
+--------+---------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+
| admin  | members | name   | 123 | Joe       | Bob       |
+--------+---------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+
| admin  | members | age    | 123 | 32        | 40        |
+--------+---------+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

Obviously to populate this table you can see why I need to extract the values.  Ideally I'd like to do it from existing MySQL query strings, passed into my PHP function (to handle existing code), but if I need to implement new PHP functions I'm open to suggestions.

Regex seems both complicated and painful since I'd have to format it for each column name for every table.  Is there any parsing solution for this problem out there?

Comment: Do you use any framework? It's a bad practice to parse SQL's. For example in Zend Framework you can override update() or insert() and simply get SQL schema.

Comment: You need two things: an audit table and a trigger! The audit table would be with new and old values for each field. I would create an audit table for every table I think it is better than have one for all tables. And the trigger will do the heavy job.

Comment: No, no frameworks currently in plage.  I'm not inclined to have a separate table for each other table because that literally doubles the database size (in number of tables/columns alone).

Comment: @JorgeCampos trigger work if only few tables involves, because you need to create 1 trigger for each table.

Comment: @Melon you can create a trigger for every table and every trigger call just one procedure. And I don't think that it is a problem a trigger per table. I've worked in many systems with huge database with a trigger per table (3k, 5k tables). And you can do it dynamically here is an example: [MySQL Audit Logging Triggers](http://uber-code.blogspot.com.br/2011/02/mysql-audit-logging-triggers.html)

Comment: @JorgeCampos : every day you learn something, I did not think to create dynamically, you're absolutely right !

Comment: @Bing see if the link I show to Melon works for you (two comments up).